# Netty 4 - Is there a strategy to attach an app/service level ID to a Future and have it echoed back in operationComplete(future)? Other strategy?

Tags: netty

With Netty 4, when calling write(msg) with a service that handles a high number of messages I currently have one write listener.

Is there a strategy to attach a service/app level ID to a Future.  This way when the write listener operationComplete(Future) fires I can have that ID echoed back to me.  This would allow me to keep one listener (and not have a MAP lookup) as well as not having to have a listener instance for every write.   Other strategies?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own ChannelPromise which includes this id and pass the ChannnelPromise as last argument into the write call. Netty itself does not support this.

Comment: Thanks Norman.   That seems to be exactly what I am looking for.  I extended DefaultChannelPromise and simply pass in the object I want to grab for a particular write operation.   When the listener operationComplete() fires the future is of this promise instance so I can get at the object in question